FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "replica_user" while taking pg_basebackup in postgres v15.9
I am setting up streaming replication , on primary , I have already added 3following in my pg_hba.conf file
host    replication     replica_user            xx.xx.xx.xxx/24       md5
also have done
listen_address = '*'
But while taking pg_basebackup on standby, I am getting this error:
pg_basebackup: error: connection to server at "xx.xx.xx.xxx", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "replica_user"
Here is my backup command:
pg_basebackup -h xx.xx.xx.xxx -D /var/lib/pgsql/data/ -U replica_user -P -v -R -X stream -C -S slaveslot1

Replication section of pg_hba.conf file:
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the 
# replication privilege. 
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 
#host replication all 3.81.214.204/32 md5 
local replication all peer 
host replication all 0.0.0.0/0 ident 
host replication all ::1/128 ident 
host replication replica_user xx.xx.xx.xxx/16 md5

Any recommendation on how can I make it work ?

Perhaps the backup connection matches an earlier line in pg_hba.conf -- please show the entire file.


Did you read here pg_basebackup for the conditions that need to be met for a pg_basebackup from a standby server? 2) a) Why are you using ident? b) Are you sure the ident process is working? Add answers as text update to question text.


Did you read here pg_basebackup for the conditions that need to be met for a pg_basebackup from a standby server?

Yes, I did.


a) Why are you using ident?


I am not, I have shared that I am using md5, kindly check the question.

b) Are you sure the ident process is working?
NA

@mustaccio
Here is my pg_hba.conf for master RDS :
Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the # replication privilege.
'host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
#host replication all 3.81.214.204/32 md5
local replication all peer host replication all 0.0.0.0/0 ident
host replication all ::1/128 ident
host replication replica_user xx.xx.xx.xxx/16 md5'
Last entry is for my DB i am trying to connect to

You should add this information to your question, properly formatted -- don't leave it in a comment.

Per pg_hba.conf:

The first record with a matching connection type, client address, requested database, and user name is used to perform authentication.

In your case that would be host replication all 0.0.0.0/0 ident which fails as per the error message. You need to move host replication replica_user xx.xx.xx.xxx/16 md5 to the line above the 0.0.0.0/0 ident line so:
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the 
# replication privilege. 
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 
#host replication all 3.81.214.204/32 md5 
local replication all peer 
host replication replica_user xx.xx.xx.xxx/16 md5
host replication all 0.0.0.0/0 ident 
host replication all ::1/128 ident 

